# Проблемы с алгоритмом из книги "Алгоритмы: построение и анализ"

Tags: c, алгоритм

Здравствуйте! В книге представлен следующий алгоритм:

**Insertion Sort**

```
for j = 2 to A. length
    key = A[j]
    // Вставка A[j] в отсортированную последовательность A [ l .. j — 1].
    i = j - 1
    while г > 0 и A[i] > key
        A[i + 1] = A[i]
        i = i - 1
A[i + 1] = key
```

Перевел его в следующий код на `Си`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define COUNT_NUMBERS 6

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int numbers[COUNT_NUMBERS] = {5, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3};

    printf("Input array:");
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT_NUMBERS; ++i) printf(" %i", numbers[i]);
    printf("\n");

    for (int i = 1; i < COUNT_NUMBERS; i++) {
        int key = numbers[i];
        int j = i - 1;

        while (j > 0 && numbers[j] > key) {
            numbers[j+1] = numbers[j];
            j--;
        }

        numbers[j+1] = key;
    }

    printf("Output array:");
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT_NUMBERS; ++i) printf(" %i", numbers[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод работы программы:

```
Input array: 5 2 4 6 1 3
Output array: 5 1 2 3 4 6
```

Подскажите, в чем ошибка. За ранее спасибо!

Comment: `while (j >= 0...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В алгоритме

```
while i > 0 и A[i] > key
```

Но обратите внимание, что там индексы считают с 1, так что проверка в коде на C должна выглядеть как

```
while( j >= 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Добрый вечер.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define COUNT_NUMBERS 6

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int numbers[COUNT_NUMBERS] = {5, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3};

    printf("Input array:");
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT_NUMBERS; ++i) printf(" %i", numbers[i]);
    printf("\n");

    int j, tmp;
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT_NUMBERS; i++){
        j = i;

        while (j > 0 && numbers[j] < numbers[j-1]){
            tmp = numbers[j];
            numbers[j] = numbers[j-1];
            numbers[j-1] = tmp;
            j--;
        }
    }

    printf("Output array:");
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT_NUMBERS; ++i) printf(" %i", numbers[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Попробуйте такое исправление.